# Dialog Result Always returning "Cancel" on button click

Tags: c#, dialog

I have a form PatientInformation which has a datagridview for displaying existing records in the Database. I also have another form for updating the records present in the datagridview.

Hence I need to refresh the datagridview for taking the updates into consideration. I have 2 buttons (Cancel,Update) on the Update Form. Now the problem lies here: My Dialog result is returning 'Cancel' always even after I click the Update button.

My form also contains a method for **Form Closed event**. Is this what is causing the problem?

My calling statements are as follows :

```
diagResult = patientUpdateVlObject.ShowDialog();
if (diagResult.ToString() == "Update")
{
   dtgrdviewSearchOutput.Refresh();
   DipslayMessage("Record Updated Successfuly!!");
}
else
   //Do nothing.
```

and my form closed method in the Update Form is as follows :

```
private void PatientUpdate_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `diagResult.ToString() == "Update"`, because when you do so you're converting the control name to string.

To fix such problem you should modify your code to something like that:

```
private void buttonMessageBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Click \"OK\" if you agree with this", "MessageBoxTest", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User clicked in \"OK\"");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User clicked in \"Cancel\"");
    }
}
```

In this example I removed the `ToString` method and now I'm comparing it to `DialogResult.OK` (the MessageBox.Show Method returns a DialogResult object, so you can't compare it to a string as you did).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you're checking the name:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz8edb.aspx

```
        if (diagResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           dtgrdviewSearchOutput.Refresh();
           DipslayMessage("Record Updated Successfuly!!");
        }
```